# react component does not render and it only appears in inspect section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, components

I have a react component with bootstrap and functions renders fine even the component appears in HTML inspect section but the problem is the component that I render does not appear on the page I can just inspect
[image]

and here is the code of the component that I use.

```js
function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: so where is your button in your page? have you imported equivalent css from library?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a Model, and you set `show = false` by default.

```
 const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
```

Comment: Sorry but no ,there is no problem with that I tried it

Comment: it shows the model in inspection but it does not appear on the screen.

Comment: Some UI components will simply set `display: none` (which hides the component but allows it to exist in the HTML) instead of not mounting it to achieve better performance. This really depends on what UI framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because I have two different with different versions of bootstrap CSS libraries so that is my solution by removing one of the bootstrap and restructuring the whole document.
Thanks to everyone.